# <sup> tag is not working on email on android devices

Tags: javascript, html, angular, email

I am parsing the template using angular and generating a email .

> controller code

```
//htmlTemplateDom is the template
var div = angular.element("div#emailContent").append(htmlTemplateDom);
var htmlCompiledDom = $compile(htmlTemplateDom)($scope);
$timeout(function(){
   var divHTML=angular.element("div#emailContent").html();
   //and using this divHTML in the email.   
},500);
```

> Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8;' />
</head>

<body>
   <!-- some html code which is working as expected-->
   the 2 is not going up in android -> <sup>2</sup>
</body>
</html>
```

So the  tag isnt working and is coming as plain 2 in the email.
Someone Help!!!

Comment: Does your email client supports `<sup>`? Do you apply style for it?

Comment: its gmail on android. the by default one

Comment: I guess it isnt allowing any kind of formatting to text.

Comment: Well gmail supports CSS

Comment: but it isnt coming for android.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `vertical-align: super;` instead of `<sup>` tag

or

```
sup { 
    line-height: 0; 
    font-size: 70%; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: not working. I guess it isnt allowing any kind of formatting to text.

Comment: can you try this: line-height: 0; font-size: 70%;